# My App shows only a black screen on iPod

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ipod-touch

My app is in productions an works correctly in all devices except the iPod touch, which only shows a black screen when start the app.
Does any body knows which could be the problem?
The iPod touch is running with the 4.2.1 iOS version.
Thnks

Comment: is maybe something realted to the Default.png image, is the iPod using the same of iPhone?

Comment: I'm assuming you have a device to hand? Is there anything useful in the console? Does it enter the app delegate?

Comment: Finally I get the solution, in MyApp-info.plist it miss the iPod MainWindow, which will use the default mainwindow.xib, now i have:

![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkhan.png

I hope this can help somebody!

Comment: Happy to hear you fixed it :)

Comment: @ValentiGoClimb You should post that as an answer since it appears to be correct and the other ones are not!

Comment: @ValentiGoClimb It is correct solution please add as answer so that others can get solution quickly thanks.

Answer (score 6):

As @[ValentiGoClimb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/757038/valentigoclimb) mentioned in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290345/my-app-shows-only-a-black-screen-on-ipod#comment7352294_6290345), Xcode has bad defaults when generating the Info.plist file; it only sets the Storyboard keys for iPads and iPhones, not iPod Touches.

```
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad</key>
<string>iPadStoryboardFileName</string>
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile~iphone</key>
<string>iPhoneStoryboardFileName</string>
```

I haven't found a good way to edit this under the General Project settings screen in Xcode (which is why this problem most likely exists), so adding the key manually in the Info.plist file works well.

```
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>iPhoneStoryboardFileName</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

1. Open your mainwindow's xib file
2. select window in xib file
3. in inspector window select first tab
4. check mark the "visible at launch"

Comment: clear build + delete content of build folder + delete from simulator also not working??

Comment: not working. Remember that I only have the problem in iPod Touch. How do you do to deploy in simulator the iPod??¿

Comment: delete the app from device and then clean build.

Answer (score 0):

Your iPod is supposed to have the retina display.

so just try using Default@2x.png .

And also please make sure to have this in resources.

Comment: Did you checked with this solution ?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I’m using `XIB` not `Storyboard`.
But with Xcode 10 it’s set as “`MainStoryBoard`” as Main Interface in target setting.

So I have changed from “`MainStoryBoard`” to “`MainWindow`” and worked for me.

[image: Was Problem]
[image: Fixed]
[image: Using XIB as Main Interface]