# App shows black screen on ipod

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, storyboard, ipod

This app is universal and running perfectly fine on all other devices except iPod. I've used two storyboard.

This is the code which i've written in the `AppDelegate`.

```
 -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {    
    UIImage* background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation-bar-background"];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:background forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"black-back-button"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"black-back-button-landscape"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];

    [[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"knob-button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: What is OS version of your iPod? And for what OS version you have complied your app?

Comment: iPod1? put a break point in didFinishLaunching does it work if yes then its too heavy for iPod

Comment: iOS 6 is installed on the ipod and it comes in didFinishlaunching.It is iPod touch.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399075/screen-size-of-iphone-5/13399220#13399220

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to add the main storyboard in the project.So,if anyone else get into the same problem then double check whether you have added a storyboard in main storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the image(make sure the new trial image is png formatted) and see if it is showing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe .. your iPod capabilities.. are not "compliant" (armv7, etc) with your release code
What iPod generation? 
Check - again - your iPod capabilities: http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/10/30/uirequireddevicecapabilities-and-device-compatibility-matrix

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in how Xcode and how it generates the defaults when handling the storyboards in universal apps. Checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21632289/703530