# UIViewController not called on iPod

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ipod-touch

I have an app working well on all iPhone/iPad devices with iOS 6 and above, but not on iPod-Touch running the same version iOS.
Investigated and found that NO UIViewController subclass functions are called at all. Here are the function called comparison between iPhone and iPod-Touch:

iPhone, called in sequence:

```
UIViewController::initWithCoder
UIApplicationDelegate::didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
UIViewController::viewDidLoad
UIViewController::viewWillAppear
UIApplicationDelegate::applicationDidBecomeActive
```

but with iPod Touch, NO UIViewController functions are called:

```
UIApplicationDelegate::didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
UIApplicationDelegate::applicationDidBecomeActive
```

as a result on iPod there is nothing displayed and the app hangs. All suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Really don't think I should do this to make it work but it works finally:

http://markpospesel.wordpress.com/2011/09/27/just-a-black-screen-on-the-ipod-touch/

and

[My App shows only a black screen on iPod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290345/my-app-shows-only-a-black-screen-on-ipod)